# C++ containers, covariance and template

Tags: c++, templates, covariant

I have some issues to find a relevant solution to my problem.
I have to return some data from a class, and the type of data kind of depends on the class.
My first solution was this :

```
class Base
{
    virtual QVector<Data*> getData() const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   virtual QVector<DerviedData*> getData() const = 0;
};
```

But I know this is impossible, even if DerivedData extends Data, because of invalid covariant return types.

So I came up with another idea which implies template. What I did is I turned the Base class into a template class :

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
    virtual QVector<T*> getData() const = 0;
}
```

And then I could write a `Derived`constructor like that :

```
Derived::Derived() : Base<DerivedData>() {}
```

But know I have another problem. Suppose that I write another class, which has a method taking any Base class in parameters.

```
void Foo::doSomething(Base* b) { 
    b->getData(); 
}
```

This does not compile and says

*invalid use of template-name 'Base' without an argument list*

which I understand perfectly.

Supposing that my code will look like that :

```
DerivedClass1 d1;
DerivedClass2 d2;
DerivedClass3 d3;

this->doSomething(&d1);
this->doSomething(&d2);
this->doSomething(&d3);
```

What are my solutions here ? May I do something like "templating" the method doSomething ?

```
this->doSomething<DerivedData>(&d1);
```

With a protoype like

```
template<class T>
void doSomething(Base<T>* b);
```

Is that possible ? Is that a good way of thinking ?
Coming from Java, I used to resolve such problems by using wildcards

```
abstract List<? extends Data> getData();
```

But I heard there is stricly speaking no such things in C++ (more or less simulable with such things as  `std::is_base_of`).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: _Is that possible?_ Well.. Did you try it?

Comment: Is `DerivedData` inheriting from `Data`? Then it's not a problem.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius : No, I didn't try. Since this feels like odd to me, I wanted to know if it was a better solution, but I will give it a try.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : Yes DerivedData inherits from Data. But what problem are you talking about ?

Comment: @B.Oudot So, why didn't you try it? It seems that trying to compile such a code would be quicker, that writing up a question on SO, and, it, in turn may answer your question.

Comment: If DerivedData inherits from Data, then can't you just return QVector<Data*> from Derived::getData()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let `Derived::getData(`) return `QVector<Data*>`. When you need to use it, find out if the pointers in `QVector` is to `Data` or `DerivedData`, using `dynamic_cast` or similar method.